# How do I code this second entry filter on C#

Tags: c#

I have an entry filter that affects ALL markets selected during backtest. I want to add another entry filter which affects some markets so that the first entry filter can affect other markets. I am having a challenge in coding that

```
{
    if(Close.Count<=100) return;

    if(Opens()>0){
        CheckForExit();
        UpdateFailSafe();
    }

    if(Opens()==0)
    {
        if(sma50.LookBack(1)>sma150.LookBack(1) && Close.LookBack(1) > Highest())
        {
            Long();
        }

        if(sma50.LookBack(1)<sma150.LookBack(1) && Close.LookBack(1) < Lowest())
        {
            Short();
        }
    }
```

So how do I modify the first and add the below second entry filter to work on some markets:

SMA 25 > SMA 100 = Long....but it fetches some market like GC, SI, ES, TU etc

SMA 25 < SMA 100 = Short....but it fetches some markets only e.g. PA, NQ, GI etc.

Response will be highly appreciated

Comment: If "Entry Filter" is some specific terminology for a product/library it would probably help if you identified it in your question. It you do that, it *may* become clear *how* markets interact with the above code but for *general* C# there's too many unclear parts of this question as it currently stands.